# logs of build warnings in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, performance, build, warnings

I have 2220 build warnings in my app.Will it affect performance of app in any way?If so, how can I get the logs for the performance issue in run time from an app in production?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No it won't affect your application performance on runtime. but you can reduce the number of warning by following suitable suggestion provided by xcode.